# RightBarButtonItem disappears when view appears again

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My problem is that my RightBarButtonItem, in my navigationItem, disappears after the view appears a second time. The first time the view loads, it displays properly, but the second time it disappears completely.

The button is init'd in viewWillAppear as such:

```
UIBarButtonItem *optionsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:roundedButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = optionsButton;
```

and i remembered to call super

I only touch my navigation controller once more:

http://pastebin.com/udviCe0Y

Any ideas how this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a category to add custom image on navigation bar. Override drawRect method by creating a category on navigation bar. Search on google you will find it. If not let me know. I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your BarButton in ViewWillAppear method,so every time when your View Will appear ,you will find the bar button.
This will resolve your problem.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

{

}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

If you check the subviews of your navigation-bar, you will see that the barButtons are removed and you have to create new ones.

I tried to store the arrays with buttons before, and add them in viewWillAppear but it did not work so I stayed with create new ones in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

I have always added bar button items in viewDidLoad and never had any problem like yours.  Try moving the bar button addition to viewDidLoad.

Comment: Jamihash, it seems that from the code I posted above, where I set the bar's background by adding a new subview, the background is going over top of the buttons... Any idea how I could set the bar's custom background in a different way without going over top of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in viewWillAppear:

    `UIBarButtonItem *optionsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:roundedButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = optionsButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = optionsButton;`