# rightBarButtonItem disappears on pop in iOS-9 and iOS-10

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I already read multiple posts regarding this, but couldn't get it working.

Posts I already read:

1. [Custom rightBarButtonItem disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970948/custom-rightbarbuttonitem-disappearing)
2. [RightBarButtonItem disappears when view appears again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073465/rightbarbuttonitem-disappears-when-view-appears-again)

I have a `ViewController-A` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. The `navigation bar` of the controller contains a `rightBarButtonItem`. Code for adding `rightBarButtonItem`:

```
let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "HomeSearch"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(navigateToSearchScreen))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton
```

When another `ViewController-B` is pushed in the navigation stack and popped back, the `rightBarButtonItem` disappears from the navigation bar.

Comment: where you called this code `viewdload or else`

Comment: Please write this code in viewwillappear method

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I called it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @JAINESHDOSHI I tried that already. But it’s not working.

Comment: share you code may be you have write some thing not logic

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish I've already shared the code that I have used.

Comment: Navigation process you just add button to navigationbar, where is navigation process , back action ...etc

Comment: viewDidDisappear contains any kind of code ? in either of the classes , or anywhere is rightbarbutton assigned nil

Comment: Actually, I added the code to add `rightBarButton` in `viewDidAppear`. But it is still not smooth. I checked in the UI debugger that when I pop the controller, the button is still there, only the hierarchy of `UINavigationBar` is changed. I don't understand what could be the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think in nextViewcontroller you hide the navigation right bar so When you pop then nav button will not display So You have to add right bar button in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "HomeSearch"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(navigateToSearchScreen))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton
    }
```

Comment: Navigation bar is visible. Just the rightBarButton disappeared.

Comment: Yes, Only right bar button hide. Have you tried this in viewWillAppear?